# How to compareTo or Count Difference from two date in android studio

Tags: android, date, compareto

i already tried to compareTo two date in android studio like this

```
        String dtThen = "13-10-2013";
        Date dateThen = formatter.parse(dtThen);

        String dtNow = "15-10-2013";
        Date dateNow = formatter.parse(dtNow);

        if (dateThen.compareTo(dateNow)==0) {

            Log.d("if different date is 0");

        } else if (dateThen.compareTo(dateNow)==1) {

            Log.d("if different date is 1");


        } else if (dateThen.compareTo(dateNow)>1) {

            Log.d("if different date is 2");

        }
```

in my code are three condition, i want make condition compare date is 0 , 1 and greater than 1

and if compareTo is 0 is work, but how to make compareTo same with 1 and greater than 1

how ??

Comment: Please check my updated solution and let me know in case of concern

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also create the timeStamp from your date and compare that timeStamp.
For creating the date into timeStamp below is the example

```
String dtThen ="13-10-2013";
String dtNow = "15-10-2013";
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
Date dateThen = (Date)formatter.parse(dtThen ); 
Date dateNow  = (Date)formatter.parse(dtNow );
```

And now u can compare the timeStamp as u want to like below

```
  if(dateThen.getTime()>dateNow.getTime())
   {
      //      Do some thing here
   }
   else
   {
     //Do other stuff here
   }
```

For getting the difference between the date, than u need to use this following code:-

```
long diff = dateThen.getTime() - dateNow.getTime();
long seconds = diff / 1000;
long minutes = seconds / 60;
long hours = minutes / 60;
long days = hours / 24;
System.out.println("YOUR DAY HOUR AND MINUTE DIFFERENCE==>>> "+ days +" "+hours +"  "+minutes +"  "+seconds);
```

And at the  last **day** difference u can count as follow

```
if (days ==0) {

    Log.d("if different date is 0");

} else if (days ==1) {

    Log.d("if different date is 1");


} else if (days >1) {

    Log.d("if different date is 2");

}
```

Comment: how to make if i want make date difference 2 or more ?

Comment: i will make three condition, if different date == 0 , if different date ==1 and if different date > 1

Comment: @MegiFernanda Have u tried above code?? ..In my above code "days" will display the difference of the date...The difference can be any thing according to the date...U can easily manage using my code..

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below following methods to get the day difference.

```
public static int getDateDifference(String dtThen, String dtNow, String format) {

    // Converting String to Date
    Date dateThen = convertStingToDate(dtThen, format);
    Date dateNow = convertStingToDate(dtNow, format);

    // converting Date to Calendar object
    Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
    now.setTime(dateNow);
    Calendar theDay = Calendar.getInstance();
    theDay.setTime(dateThen);

    // Getting the difference in milliseconds
    long diffMillis = now.getTimeInMillis() - theDay.getTimeInMillis();

    // Converting milliseconds into number of days
    int daysDiff = (int) (diffMillis / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));

    return daysDiff;
}

public static Date convertStingToDate(String inputDate, String format) {
    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(format, Locale.getDefault());

    Date date = null;
    try {
        date = simpleDateFormat.parse(inputDate);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return date;
}
```

you can call the above method like this from your code,

```
    String dtThen = "13-10-2012";
    String dtNow = "15-10-2013";
    String format = "dd-MM-yyyy";

    int daysDiff = getDateDifference(dtThen, dtNow, format);

    Log.d(TAG, "Day difference: " + daysDiff);
```

It will give exact day difference.

Answer (score 0):

Here is Code:

```
Date d2 = null;
                Date d1 = null;
                Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                try {
                    d2 = formatter.parse(formatter.format(c.getTime()));
                    d1 = formatter.parse(preferance.getDate());//Returns 15/10/2012
                } catch (java.text.ParseException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                int diffInDays = (int) ((d1.getTime() - d2.getTime()) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
                //Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "diff"+diffInDays, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.d(TAG, "initWheel3: " + diffInDays);
                System.out.println(diffInDays);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//Given you are using a valid parser

     long logTheDifferenceOfDays(Date d1, Date d2) {
                long diff = d2.getTime() - d1.getTime();
                if (diff ==0) {
                   Log.d("if different date is 0");
                } else if(diff==86400*1000||diff==-86400*1000){
                   Log.d("if different date is 1");
                } else {
                   Log.d("if different date more than one");
                }

            }
```